# Compatible versions of Gwt, Gxt and Maven

Tags: gwt, maven, gxt, gwt-maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

now I'm using in my project GWT 1.7 and I need to upgrade to GWT 2. Also I have:

GXT 2.0.1
Maven 2.2.1
gwt-maven-plugin 1.1
maven-compiler-plugin 2.0.2 (and it's source and target configuration is 1.6)

So I've changed GWT version to 2.0.4, but my GXT version seems to be incompatible with it. The minimum version of GXT i've found is 2.2.5 but with it my project looks... weird :) So, is there older compatible version of it?

And my maven doesn't work with new gwt as well. I tried different versions of gwt-mavten-plugin, and all of them throw different errors. Maybe I have to use different maven or maven-compiler-plugin?

***UPDATE***

GWT: 2.0.4, GXT: 2.2.5, gwt-maven-plugin 2.1.0, maven-compiler-plugin 2.1

Project builds in Idea, but when I ran mvn clean install:

```
    [WARNING] You're project declares dependency on gwt-user 2.0.4. This plugin is designed for version 2.1.0
[WARNING] You're project declares dependency on gwt-user 2.0.4. This plugin is designed for version 2.1.0
[INFO] Compiling module com.dataswell.portal.ui.Application
[INFO]    Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/CrossSiteIframeLoadingStrategy.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 21: The import com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 36: The type CrossSiteIframeLoadingStrategy must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadingStrategy.startLoadingFragment(int, AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadErrorHandler)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 99: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 136: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/CrossSiteLoadingStrategy.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 21: The import com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 34: The type CrossSiteLoadingStrategy must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadingStrategy.startLoadingFragment(int, AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadErrorHandler)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 97: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 153: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/XhrLoadingStrategy.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 18: The type com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.AsyncFragmentLoader.HttpDownloadFailure is not visible
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 19: The import com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.AsyncFragmentLoader.HttpInstallFailure cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 20: The import com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 50: The type XhrLoadingStrategy must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadingStrategy.startLoadingFragment(int, AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadErrorHandler)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 129: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 131: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 133: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 164: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 198: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 219: LoadTerminatedHandler cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 249: HttpInstallFailure cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 253: HttpDownloadFailure cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/prefetch/Prefetcher.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 55: The method setPrefetchQueue(int[]) is undefined for the type AsyncFragmentLoader
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 74: The method startPrefetching() is undefined for the type AsyncFragmentLoader
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 86: The method stopPrefetching() is undefined for the type AsyncFragmentLoader
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/prefetch/RunAsyncCode.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 63: The method isAlreadyLoaded(int) is undefined for the type AsyncFragmentLoader
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/testing/StubScheduler.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 51: The method scheduleEntry(Scheduler.RepeatingCommand) of type StubScheduler must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 56: The method scheduleEntry(Scheduler.ScheduledCommand) of type StubScheduler must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 61: The method scheduleFinally(Scheduler.RepeatingCommand) of type StubScheduler must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/AutoDirectionHandler.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 35: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.HasDirectionEstimator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 74: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.WordCountDirectionEstimator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 103: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DirectionEstimator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/BidiPolicy.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 29: The method hasAnyRTL() is undefined for the type LocaleInfo
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/impl/CurrencyDataJso.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 37: Only one JavaScriptObject type may implement the methods of an interface that declared methods. The interface (com.google.gwt.i18n.client.CurrencyData) is implemented by both (com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.CurrencyDataImpl) and (com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.CurrencyDataJso)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 51: The method getDefaultFractionDigits() in the type CurrencyDataImpl is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 59: The method isDeprecated() in the type CurrencyDataImpl is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 63: The method isSpaceForced() in the type CurrencyDataImpl is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 67: The method isSpacingFixed() in the type CurrencyDataImpl is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 71: The method isSymbolPositionFixed() in the type CurrencyDataImpl is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 75: The method isSymbolPrefix() in the type CurrencyDataImpl is not applicable for the arguments (int)
[INFO]       [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.0/gwt-dev-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/dev/jjs/intrinsic/com/google/gwt/lang/Cast.java'
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 29: Referencing field 'java.lang.Object.castableTypeMap': unable to resolve field, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 29: Referencing field 'java.lang.Object.castableTypeMap': unable to resolve field, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 38: Referencing field 'java.lang.Object.castableTypeMap': unable to resolve field, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 38: Referencing field 'java.lang.Object.castableTypeMap': unable to resolve field, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]       [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.0/gwt-dev-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/dev/jjs/intrinsic/com/google/gwt/lang/Util.java'
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 27: Referencing field 'java.lang.Object.castableTypeMap': unable to resolve field, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 35: Referencing field 'java.lang.Object.castableTypeMap': unable to resolve field, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DoubleBox.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.client.DoubleRenderer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 29: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.client.DoubleParser; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasAutoHorizontalAlignment.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 30: AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 30: No source code is available for type AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 38: AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 38: No source code is available for type AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 39: AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 54: AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 54: No source code is available for type AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 77: AutoHorizontalAlignmentConstant cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasDirectionalSafeHtml.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.HasSafeHtml; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 33: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IntegerBox.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 27: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.client.IntegerRenderer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.client.IntegerParser; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LongBox.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.client.LongRenderer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 29: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.client.LongParser; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBox.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 42: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.shared.Renderer<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 42: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.shared.Parser<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 50: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.HasDirectionEstimator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 51: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.client.IsEditor<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 51: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.ui.client.adapters.ValueBoxEditor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 84: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.shared.Parser<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 85: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.shared.Renderer<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 159: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DirectionEstimator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 45: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.client.IsEditor<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 45: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.TakesValueEditor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 49: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.shared.Renderer<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 50: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.view.client.ProvidesKey<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 55: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.view.client.SimpleKeyProvider<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 84: The method of(TakesValue<T>) in the type TakesValueEditor is not applicable for the arguments (ValueListBox<T>)
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValuePicker.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 40: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.client.IsEditor<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 40: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.client.LeafValueEditor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 42: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractCell<C>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 43: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.text.shared.Renderer<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 50: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 57: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellList<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 58: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.view.client.SingleSelectionModel<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 64: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.view.client.SelectionChangeEvent.Handler; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 65: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.view.client.SelectionChangeEvent; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 83: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.editor.client.adapters.TakesValueEditor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 83: The method of(TakesValue<T>) in the type TakesValueEditor is not applicable for the arguments (ValuePicker<T>)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 90: The method asWidget() of type ValuePicker<T> must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/RichTextAreaImplOldMozilla.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 39: The method setFirstFocusImpl() of type RichTextAreaImplOldMozilla must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 44: The method setFocusImpl(boolean) of type RichTextAreaImplOldMozilla must override or implement a supertype method
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 47: The method setFocusImpl(boolean) is undefined for the type RichTextAreaImplMozilla
[INFO]       [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.0.4/gwt-user-2.0.4.jar!/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Arrays.java'
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 1348: Referencing method 'com.google.gwt.lang.LongLib.compare([D[D)': unable to resolve method, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]          [WARN] Line 1358: Referencing method 'com.google.gwt.lang.LongLib.compare([D[D)': unable to resolve method, expect subsequent failures
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/logging/Level.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImpl; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImplNull; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/logging/Logger.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LoggerImpl; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LoggerImplNull; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/vskovalenko/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.1.0/gwt-user-2.1.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/prefetch/RunAsyncCode.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 63:  The method isAlreadyLoaded(int) is undefined for the type AsyncFragmentLoader
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/home/vskovalenko/dataswell/trunk/source/portal/ui/src/main/java/com/dataswell/portal/ui/client/account/rpc/AccountServiceAsync.java
[INFO]       Adding '89' new generated units
[INFO]          Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]             [WARN] Warnings in '/home/vskovalenko/dataswell/trunk/source/portal/ui/target/.generated/com/dataswell/portal/ui/client/account/rpc/AccountService_TypeSerializer.java'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 283: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializableException'
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/home/vskovalenko/dataswell/trunk/source/portal/ui/src/main/java/com/dataswell/portal/ui/client/dataset/rpc/DatasetServiceAsync.java
[INFO]       Adding '22' new generated units
[INFO]          Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]             [WARN] Warnings in '/home/vskovalenko/dataswell/trunk/source/portal/ui/target/.generated/com/dataswell/portal/ui/client/dataset/rpc/DatasetService_TypeSerializer.java'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 153: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ChangeListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 158: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ClickListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 163: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FocusListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 168: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormHandlerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 173: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.KeyboardListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 178: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LoadListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 183: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MouseListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 188: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MouseWheelListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 193: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 198: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 203: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 208: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TableListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 213: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeListenerCollection'
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/home/vskovalenko/dataswell/trunk/source/portal/ui/src/main/java/com/dataswell/portal/ui/client/EdgarOnlineServiceAsync.java
[INFO]       Adding '7' new generated units
[INFO]          Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]             [WARN] Warnings in '/home/vskovalenko/dataswell/trunk/source/portal/ui/target/.generated/com/dataswell/portal/ui/client/EdgarOnlineService_TypeSerializer.java'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 96: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ChangeListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 101: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ClickListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 106: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FocusListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 111: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormHandlerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 116: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.KeyboardListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 121: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LoadListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 126: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MouseListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 131: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MouseWheelListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 136: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 141: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 146: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 151: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TableListenerCollection'
[INFO]                [WARN] Line 156: Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeListenerCollection'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
```

Comment: One question per, er, question please; and show the errors for the gwt/gwt-maven-plugin combo you think is the correct one.

Comment: Ok, i did it, see the errors above

Comment: `[WARNING] You're project declares dependency on gwt-user 2.0.4. This plugin is designed for version 2.1.0` What makes you think this is the correct combo? (BTW 2.0.4 is very old –though less old than 1.7–, can't you upgrate to a recent/decent version of GWT?)

Comment: I haven't found gwt-maven-plugin for gwt 2.0.4. I will try to upgrade gwt to 2.1 but i'm aware of compatibility, 'cause the project is REALLY big and i don't want it totally go down.

Comment: gwt-maven-plugin 1.2 [should work](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT/fixforversion/15420) with GWT 2.0.4. Starting with 2.1, gwt-maven-plugin is built against, and compatible with, a specific version of GWT, and thus switched to the same versionning scheme.

Comment: Ok, and what maven-compiler-plugin should i use with gwt 2.0.4 and gwt-maven-plugin 1.2?

Comment: It doesn't matter (I suppose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its metioned in the FAQ of the gwt-maven-plugin - http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/faq.html

### **How to set the version of GWT to compile my project ?**

gwt-maven-plugin is tied to a version of GWT SDK. gwt-maven-plugin must match the GWT DSK version. To use Maven with GWT release **prior to GWT 2.1**, `use` **gwt-maven-plugin 1.2** and read the documentation.

### For GWT and GXT compatibility reference GXT forums

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147726-Ext-GWT-2.2.5-Now-Available

Answer (score 0):

after searching for a while i found a repository which has the "gxt2.2.5-gwt22.jar" artifact, im writing this because i saw a few threads on stackoverflow where i got redirected from google while searching, so for the people having dificulties how to integrate the jar to your project pom.

add this to the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
   <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.5-gwt22</version>
</dependency>
```

and add this repository:

```
<repository>
   <id>maven.ucdavis.edu-releases</id>
   <name>maven.ucdavis.edu-releases</name>
   <url>http://maven.ucdavis.edu:80/artifactory/sakai-local</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Good to know. I'll be sure to get that added to the documentation. :)

Comment: May I ask why you are using the older version?

Comment: im not sure but ive read somewhere that the 2.2.5 version is free to use?
so thats the only reason, correct me if im wrong :=)

Comment: 3.0.1 is the latest public release, covered either by GPLv3 (plus exceptions, see links at lower right corner of http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/license/) or a commercial license. This is the same licensing rules as GXT 2. Note that 3.0.1 only works with GWT 2.4.0 and above.